# transfer data from excel to SharePoint

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-online

I am trying to transfer data from excel to SharePoint, which was very simple to do in old SharePoint vs new.

First its not doing anything using chrome.

Second using IE i am getting error "The information cannot be pasted because the copy area and the paste area are not the same size and shape".

I have tried:
*Not clicking directly on cell, instead using arrow to go down to the column/row to paste using CTRL + V

Cant find any other solution that i can try.

Answer (score 1):

Usually you get this error because your data doesn't match its destination. To see what's in your Excel, and how it behaves in SharePoint you could try to create a list of your Excel spreadsheet.

Go to site contents > add an app > Import spreadsheet app

Compare columns between your old list and your new list and see where it differs.

Comment: thanks! but just to give it a try i exported my SharePoint list to excel and try to copy one row from excel to SharePoint list again and it still giving me same error.